# Wiki.js not running. Database Connection Error

Tags: postgresql, node-windows, wiki.js

Windows Enterprise 2016 LTSB Version 1607. Installed Wiki.js with PostgreSQL. Has Node.js installed previously (v12.16.2).

Got to [step 8](https://docs.requarks.io/install/windows) of wiki.js installation process using the Powershell:

```
node server
```

I receive this error:

```
PS C:\wiki> node server
Loading configuration from C:\wiki\config.yml... OK
2021-01-03T23:06:14.299Z [MASTER] info: =======================================
2021-01-03T23:06:14.300Z [MASTER] info: = Wiki.js 2.5.170 =====================
2021-01-03T23:06:14.301Z [MASTER] info: =======================================
2021-01-03T23:06:14.301Z [MASTER] info: Initializing...
2021-01-03T23:06:14.688Z [MASTER] info: Using database driver pg for postgres [ OK ]
2021-01-03T23:06:14.690Z [MASTER] info: Connecting to database...
2021-01-03T23:06:15.698Z [MASTER] error: Database Connection Error: ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5432
2021-01-03T23:06:15.698Z [MASTER] warn: Will retry in 3 seconds... [Attempt 1 of 10]
2021-01-03T23:06:18.700Z [MASTER] info: Connecting to database...
2021-01-03T23:06:19.703Z [MASTER] error: Database Connection Error: ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5432
2021-01-03T23:06:19.703Z [MASTER] warn: Will retry in 3 seconds... [Attempt 2 of 10]
... (you get the point)
2021-01-03T23:06:51.728Z [MASTER] error: Database Connection Error: ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5432
2021-01-03T23:06:51.729Z [MASTER] warn: Will retry in 3 seconds... [Attempt 10 of 10]
2021-01-03T23:06:54.730Z [MASTER] info: Connecting to database...
2021-01-03T23:06:55.733Z [MASTER] error: Database Initialization Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5432
```

I realize that I forgot to create a PostgreSQL, so I used pgAdmin4.28 to create a "wiki" database. Error now changed to:

```
PS C:\wiki> node server
Loading configuration from C:\wiki\config.yml... OK
2021-01-04T00:27:21.979Z [MASTER] info: =======================================
2021-01-04T00:27:21.980Z [MASTER] info: = Wiki.js 2.5.170 =====================
2021-01-04T00:27:21.981Z [MASTER] info: =======================================
2021-01-04T00:27:21.982Z [MASTER] info: Initializing...
2021-01-04T00:27:22.363Z [MASTER] info: Using database driver pg for postgres [ OK ]
2021-01-04T00:27:22.365Z [MASTER] info: Connecting to database...
2021-01-04T00:27:22.428Z [MASTER] error: Database Connection Error: 28P01 undefined:undefined
2021-01-04T00:27:22.429Z [MASTER] warn: Will retry in 3 seconds... [Attempt 1 of 10]
2021-01-04T00:27:25.431Z [MASTER] info: Connecting to database...
2021-01-04T00:27:25.501Z [MASTER] error: Database Connection Error: 28P01 undefined:undefined
2021-01-04T00:27:25.501Z [MASTER] warn: Will retry in 3 seconds... [Attempt 2 of 10]
2021-01-04T00:27:28.503Z [MASTER] info: Connecting to database...
2021-01-04T00:27:28.545Z [MASTER] error: Database Connection Error: 28P01 undefined:undefined
2021-01-04T00:27:28.546Z [MASTER] warn: Will retry in 3 seconds... [Attempt 3 of 10]
```

Please send help! I appreciate all comments. Thanks!

Comment: dw guys, I'll keep my pc online until this issue is resolved

Answer (score 6):

I had similar issue with postgres and wiki.js.
Solution was to manually create the Database in postgres, *BEFORE* you run `node server`:

```
CREATE DATABASE wiki
```

Hope that saves you the time I had to spend to figure this out.

Answer (score 4):

My environment is as follows: Windows 10 professional version number 20h2 node version v14.15.4 PostgreSQL V 13.1, the error content is as follows:

```
Loading configuration from D:\dev\workspace\wiki\config.yml... OK
2021-02-03T06:32:55.015Z [MASTER] info: =======================================
2021-02-03T06:32:55.016Z [MASTER] info: = Wiki.js 2.5.170 =====================
2021-02-03T06:32:55.016Z [MASTER] info: =======================================
2021-02-03T06:32:55.017Z [MASTER] info: Initializing...
2021-02-03T06:32:59.091Z [MASTER] info: Using database driver pg for postgres [ OK ]
2021-02-03T06:32:59.094Z [MASTER] info: Connecting to database...
2021-02-03T06:32:59.160Z [MASTER] error: Database Connection Error: 28P01 
undefined:undefined
```

You just need to config.yml The database configuration in is modified as follows:

```
db:
  type: postgres

  # PostgreSQL / MySQL / MariaDB / MS SQL Server only:
  host: localhost
  port: 5432
  user: postgres #YOU PostgreSQL USERNAME
  pass: willasas@wiki. #YOU PostgreSQL PASSWORD
  db: wiki #YOU DATABASE NAME
  ssl: false
```

Then run the code

```
node server
```

And type in the address bar of your browser `http://127.0.0.1 : 3000 /` parallel return

Answer (score 1):

After a couple hours of testing I realized some problems using postgres in wiki.js. These are some recommendations you can try in config.yml:

```
db:
  type: postgres
  
  # if you are using docker try using IP instead of localhost
  host: localhost
  port: 5432
  
  # don't use _ here. It'll cause connection error undefined.
  user: wikijs
  
  # start with letter, if you start with @ it will throw an error.
  # I used a 18 long pass without any problem. Ex:
  pass: wiki@projectW777!@
  
  # you can use _ here. Ex:
  db: prj_wiki
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to change the database password, this can help you:

```sql
ALTER USER postgres WITH PASSWORD 'xxx';
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem:

```
error: Database Connection Error: 28P01 undefined:undefined
```

I've solved it by modifying 86 line of file `/var/lib/psql/data/pg_hba.conf`, changing `ident` to `md5` and then restarted database:

```
$ sudo systemctl restart postgresql
```

Additionally I've changed password in database:

```
$ sudo -u wikijs psql -d wiki
wiki=# \password wikijs
```

After that I've successfully executed `node server`.

Answer (score 0):

Use this `docker-compose` file.

It solved my problems. Also make sure all the service names are unique, i.e. neither of the exist in your presently running docker containers

```
version: '3'
services:
  db:
    image: mysql:8.0
    logging:
      driver: "none"
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - db-data:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: mysql123!
      MYSQL_DATABASE: wiki

  wiki:
    image: requarks/wiki:2
    depends_on:
      - db
    environment:
      DB_TYPE: mysql
      DB_HOST: db
      DB_PORT: 3307
      DB_USER: root
      DB_PASS: mysql123!
      DB_NAME: wiki
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "9010:3000"

volumes:
  db-data:
```

If you rename the "db" service name, make sure to update the "DB_HOST" environment parameter too !!

Answer (score 0):

My Error Message was as followed:

```bash
Loading configuration from /wiki/config.yml... OK
2023-03-22T08:17:20.443Z [MASTER] info: =======================================
2023-03-22T08:17:20.445Z [MASTER] info: = Wiki.js 2.5.298 =====================
2023-03-22T08:17:20.445Z [MASTER] info: =======================================
2023-03-22T08:17:20.445Z [MASTER] info: Initializing...
2023-03-22T08:17:21.095Z [MASTER] info: Using database driver pg for postgres [ OK ]
2023-03-22T08:17:21.108Z [MASTER] info: Connecting to database...
2023-03-22T08:17:21.130Z [MASTER] error: Database Connection Error: ENOTFOUND undefined:undefined
2023-03-22T08:17:21.130Z [MASTER] warn: Will retry in 3 seconds... [Attempt 1 of 10]
2023-03-22T08:17:24.135Z [MASTER] info: Connecting to database...
2023-03-22T08:17:24.138Z [MASTER] error: Database Connection Error: ENOTFOUND undefined:undefined
2023-03-22T08:17:24.138Z [MASTER] warn: Will retry in 3 seconds... [Attempt 2 of 10]
```

And the solution/problem for me was the encoded Password in the secret.

I used `echo "VH43GmpYEMk9" | base64` which produced: `Vkg0M0dtcFlFTWs5Cg==`

You have to get rid of `Cg==` which is apparently the base64 encode of the new line character in the latest position.

So instead I had to use this encoded string: `Vkg0M0dtcFlFTWs5`

And just for reference this is how I ended up installing wiki.js:

```bash
helm install wiki-postgresql bitnami/postgresql -n wiki --set auth.username="wiki" --set auth.password="VH43GmpYEMk9 " --set auth.database="wiki" --set auth.postgresPassword="VH43GmpYEMk9 "
```

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
data:
  postgresql-password: Vkg0M0dtcFlFTWs5 # VH43GmpYEMk9 in base64 encoded
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: wiki
  namespace: wiki
type: Opaque
```

```bash
helm repo add requarks https://charts.js.wiki

helm repo update

helm install wiki requarks/wiki -n wiki --set postgresql.enabled=false --set postgresql.postgresqlHost=wiki-postgresql.wiki.svc.cluster.local --set postgresql.existingSecret=wiki --set postgresql.postgresqlUser=wiki
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone getting these errors and using Azure for deployment:

```
error: Database Connection Error: 28P01 

Database Connection Error: Knex: Timeout acquiring a connection. The pool is probably full. Are you missing a .transacting(trx) call?
```

You have to pay attention what database settings you config during `Postgresql` deployment:

- If you used `Flexible` server as deployment you need to provide the username the following way in your `Web App` --> `DB_USER = username@hostname`
- If you deployed your db `Single server` mode, you only need to provide it like this --> `DB_USER = username`.