# Why is my connection refused while connecting to upstream? Nginx Error 502

Tags: docker, nginx

I have 3 docker containers

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                     COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS          PORTS                                                                      NAMES
543a637e7a5b   ghcr.io/requarks/wiki:2   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   57 minutes ago   Up 8 seconds    0.0.0.0:3000->3000/tcp, :::3000->3000/tcp, 3443/tcp                        wiki_wiki_1
83bf032cace2   nginx:alpine              "/docker-entrypoint.…"   57 minutes ago   Up 57 minutes   0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp, :::80->80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:443->443/tcp, :::443->443/tcp   wiki_webserver_1
06ca7cf8095f   postgres:11-alpine        "docker-entrypoint.s…"   57 minutes ago   Up 57 minutes   5432/tcp
```

I have also looked at my main app wiki container and its logs show that it can not connect to database(it seems they are n server though)

```
2022-04-29T07:29:16.005Z [MASTER] error: Database Initialization Error: password authentication failed for user "wikijs"
```

Nginx in docker-compose.yml

```
services:

  db:
    image: postgres:11-alpine
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: wiki
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: quantoxrocks
      POSTGRES_USER: wikijs
    logging:
      driver: "none"
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - db-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data

  wiki:
    image: ghcr.io/requarks/wiki:2
    depends_on:
      - db
    environment:
      DB_TYPE: postgres
      DB_HOST: db
      DB_PORT: 5432
      DB_USER: wikijs
      DB_PASS: quantoxrocks
      DB_NAME: wiki
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    
  webserver:
    image: nginx:alpine
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    ports:
       - "443:443"
       - "80:80"            
    volumes:
      - ./nginx/conf.d:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - ./ssl:/etc/nginx/ssl        
volumes:
  db-data:
```

My conf file

```
server {
  listen 443 ssl http2;
  server_name wiki.mycomp;
  ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/mycomp.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/mycomp.key;
  ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
  ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;

  location / {
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme; # scheme: https
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_redirect off;

    proxy_pass http://wiki;
  }
}
```

I tried everything and I again get error.

```
172.68.50.35 - - [29/Apr/2022:05:29:00 +0000] "GET / HTTP/2.0" 502 157 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:99.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/99.0" "178.222.69.104"
2022/04/29 05:29:00 [error] 22#22: *12 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.68.50.35, server: wiki.mycomp, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/2.0", upstream: "http://172.22.0.4:80/favicon.ico", host: "wiki.mycomp", referrer: "https://wiki.mycomp/"
```

My server is Amazon Linux Ec2 instance. I am adding cat audit.log | grep nginx,I can not see that nginx failed.

```
ype=SERVICE_START msg=audit(1651154547.708:1254): pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='unit=nginx comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=failed'
type=SERVICE_START msg=audit(1651154574.080:1267): pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='unit=nginx comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=failed'
type=DEL_GROUP msg=audit(1651157144.425:1378): pid=11420 uid=0 auid=1000 ses=18 msg='op=delete-group grp="nginx" acct="nginx" exe="/usr/sbin/userdel" hostname=wikijs addr=? terminal=pts/0 res=success'
type=GRP_MGMT msg=audit(1651157144.425:1379): pid=11420 uid=0 auid=1000 ses=18 msg='op=delete-shadow-group grp="nginx" acct="nginx" exe="/usr/sbin/userdel" hostname=wikijs addr=? terminal=pts/0 res=success'
type=USER_CMD msg=audit(1651206496.737:14035): pid=564 uid=1000 auid=1000 ses=114 msg='cwd="/home/ec2-user/wiki/nginx/conf.d" cmd=79756D202D7920696E7374616C6C2074636D7064756D70 terminal=pts/0 res=success'
type=USER_CMD msg=audit(1651206572.593:14120): pid=1102 uid=1000 auid=1000 ses=114 msg='cwd="/home/ec2-user/wiki/nginx/conf.d" cmd=79756D202D7920696E7374616C6C207463707064756D70 terminal=pts/0 res=success'
type=USER_CMD msg=audit(1651206580.297:14126): pid=1108 uid=1000 auid=1000 ses=114 msg='cwd="/home/ec2-user/wiki/nginx/conf.d" cmd=79756D202D7920696E7374616C6C2074637064756D70 terminal=pts/0 res=success'
type=USER_CMD msg=audit(1651206845.945:14359): pid=2396 uid=1000 auid=1000 ses=114 msg='cwd="/home/ec2-user/wiki/nginx/conf.d" cmd=74637064756D70202D41202D76767676202D732039393939202D69206574683020706F7274203830 terminal=pts/0 res=success'
```

What does `res=failed'` mean?

How should the proxy_pass look like?
Why is it forwarding to 80?

Comment: Are your containers in the same docker-network? Since you posted a snipped of your docker-compose, I'm assuming they all are in the same docker-compose file? Could you maybe add the entire file?

Comment: Yes,the are.I am adding.

Comment: @Simon Can you take a look now?

Comment: can you post the entire file? (with docker-compose version)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wiki.js is listening on port 3000 and not 80. (You can see that from the [examples in the docs](https://docs.requarks.io/install/docker#examples) which all forward port 3000.)

Therefore, the solution is to set `proxy_pass` to `http://wiki:3000` instead of just `http://wiki`. (About your question why it's accessing port 80: because that's the default HTTP port! Any HTTP URL without specified port will use port 80.)

*I do wonder though why you even need nginx here in the first place because the Wiki.js Docker image comes with builtin SSL support with LetsEncrypt already... See the last of the examples linked above.*

Comment: I need because Cloudflare is hitting 443 port.

Comment: I accepted the answer,but I still have the same problem. How to check error: Database Connection Error: 28P01 undefined:undefined ? This is form docker logs

Comment: Sounds like a new problem, not the same problem. How the check: by googling it, you will find existing questions about that error here on SO as well.

Comment: Also, about CloudFlare: I still don't think you need it, you can simply forward port 3443 as 443 as shown in the examples and if you want to use your own certificate and not LetsEncrypt you can do so by mounting a config file, also explained in the docs.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65558453/wiki-js-not-running-database-connection-error